# Link issues using a:hover:after

Tags: css, pseudo-element

http://codepen.io/brianmillerkha/pen/adZdwz

In the above pen I've worked on including a few pseudo elements and I'm in over my head. I like that the light blue triangle/play button that shows up on hover, but I'm confused about why the red highlight then goes away when I specifically hover over the triangle. Is there a simple way to have both of those elements show up together?

Here is the CSS for that specific :after element

```
.container a:hover:after;
content: '\25b6';
font-size: 75px;
color: #7FDBFF;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -13%;
margin-top: 8.85%;
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=7);
```

Any advice would be very greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I updated this code at line number 74 to get what you want.

```
.container .mix:hover:after, a:hover .mix:after{
  content: attr(data-myorder)
}
```

updated **[PEN](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/BjzjJr)**

Comment: Thank you for a nice, simple fix!

Comment: @brianm And the explanation is pretty much illustrated in the second answer. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You have html elements like this:

```
<a><div></div></a>


+----------------------------------+
| 1 a:hover                        |
|    +--------------+              |
|    |  2 div:hover |              |
|    +--------------+              |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

And you're trying to use css like this:

```
div:hover:after{ } /*red background element*/
```

Now when you use `a:hover:after{}` you're no longer accessing `div:hover` so your red element is lost.

---

So, what should you do is to add this: `a:hover div:after` to your `div:hover:after` ie. like this:

```
div:hover:after, a:hover div:after{}
```

Now, when you hover to the `a` `div:after` element is shown that means you're now not losing the `div:hover:after`.

Let's see the updated [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeJevr)

Comment: Thank you for sketching it out like that. Very much appreciated!!